# How to set timezone of Centos to PST timezone?

Tags: pst, time-zone, pdt

I'm using Centos, I used following to set timezone

$ ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles localtime

To verify:

$ date

Sat Aug  8 14:04:14 PDT 2020

As you can see, the timezone set is PDT not PST, how can I set it to PST?
Since we don't want the server time to be changed by winter and summer(Daylight Saving Time ).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For programs that call `tzset()` (as they should) you can use old/non-Olson format for **env var `TZ=PST8`** but AFAICS there is no file equivalent for this (there _are_ DST-less files for EST and MST, but not CST and PST).

Comment: Generally speaking, setting a time zone that is not actually in use is not a great idea.  if you actually mean US Pacific Time, then you *would* want that to change between PST and PDT as applicable.  Otherwise, for a large portion of the year your computer's time would be an hour different than the actual local time.   The only place that uses UTC-8 year-round is the Pitcairn Islands, total population less than 50 persons.